# SELECT columns OVER (PARTITION BY column)

Tags: sql, hana

[image: TABLE BEING QUERIED (tableA)]

Suppose I want to retrieve the swimmer and their time at the 75th Percentile for each day.

This is what I was trying to do:

```
SELECT tableA.DATE, tableA.SWIMMER, tableA.TIME
                OVER (PARTITION BY tableA.DATE)
                FROM tableA
                WHERE RANK = CEIL(0.75 * NUM_OF_SWIMMERS);
```

But this errors at the OVER statement.

What's the best way to get the data I need?

Thanks!

Comment: Posting the actual error would be a lot more useful than simply noting it "errors."

Comment: ERROR: Invalid Syntax near "OVER (line 2 col 5)"

Comment: Why not just do select date, swimmer, time from tablea where rank = CEIL(0.75 * NUM_OF_SWIMMERS)? That'll return the 2 rows you need.

Comment: Yeah, your error is because an OVER() clause has to have an ORDER BY clause, but you don't seem to need one based on your requirements and data.

Comment: Literally just came here to say I tried this^ and it worked. Thanks @KyleHale.

Do you wanna submit it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is that the OVER clause of a windowing function requires an ORDER BY clause.

But assuming that num_swimmers , why not just return

```
select
   date,
swimmer,
time
from tablea
where 
RANK = CEIL(0.75 * NUM_OF_SWIMMERS)
```

?

The WHERE clause will ensure the only rows returned are the 75th percentile for a given day